# Set domainMax to max of brushed values

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

I am working with the **Overview and Detail** Vega-Lite sample at https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_overview_detail.html

I would like the Detail chart to dynamically adjust the y-axis to reflect the brushed values in the Overview chart, not the entire dataset. So when I select this valley in 2009, I want the y-axis on the Detail chart to be more like 1000 than 1500.
[image: Brushed data]

So for this modified sample, how do I dynamically set `domainMax` based on the brushed data?

```
        "y": {
          "field": "price", 
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domainMax": 1000}
        }
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOOMQAZTlKBGIgAvkuJQ5UNWgDaoTHUFx9AETh1Gj0lAHcaZXo0ABYADlMlZG0Aa30kbTgUJThZJ2UaWTI0UAAPYpAAMxo4QWV9VUxfJUwATxxfdEaEHDZtJBCQaH6O0GU2ZALynHSkBH0mbQYIGDt7ECQSmghyr0wffVWlFvKqmrr0HG0aKCaQVvb9AEcGJFldtRpSRUGXfc0VcZIAoAWQ2aAAjOZTLYYfZPN4OiAAPKkbTEaqhb7hSIrVBxBIYOA0MhYNAANgJSVS6HSmW+0z6CG2qA8IFks0RCyWKyUEBqcCgmB2bURBUaaP63xyeQKZGZbhAZQAujCldlcmx8oVymV-qdavU1Ld7oiuj0+no1sc9dUDRcrjdviani83nQPl8lBstjtrskAMJsBhvNAAZiUZCu5wq-T5sNsKqAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to zoom in is to use `"scale": {"zero": false}` *but* you also have to set `"stack": false`. According to guru @jakevdp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620705/how-to-use-zero-false-in-vega-lite-when-also-using-a-color-encoding), each area has an implicit stacked zero-height area for the group that does not appear but affects the automatically chosen axis limits.

```json
        "y": {
          "field": "price", 
          "type": "quantitative",
          "stack": false,
          "scale": {
            "zero": false
          }
        }
```

[image: Working chart]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)